# Checking result of $(MAKE) in a makefile

Tags: compilation, makefile, exit-code

I'm using a Makefile to compile my project. I get to a point which is:

```
$(MAKE) <some flags>; \
$(UPLOAD_SCRIPT)
```

The $(MAKE) line actually compiles the code, but I only want the upload script to run if the make was successful (i.e. no errors). Is there a way to do this? I'm imagining something with exit codes, storing the result in a variable, and an `if` statement, but I'm not super familiar with Makefiles.

Comment: If you're using GNU make, start here: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Answer (score 1):

Chain the 2 commands using `&&` like this instead:

```
mytarget:
    $(MAKE) <some flags> && $(UPLOAD_SCRIPT)
```

If you have more lines, and do not want to make your line look very long using `&&`, you can use `set -e`, so that the shell stops on the first error.

> **-e**  When this option is on, if a simple command fails for any of the
>   reasons listed in Consequences of Shell Errors or returns an exit
>   status value >0, and  is  not  part of the compound list following a
>   while, until, or if keyword, and is not a part of an AND or OR list,
>   and is not a pipeline preceded by the ! reserved word, then the shell
>   shall immediately exit.

```
mytarget:
    set -e; \
    cmd1; \
    cmd2
```

Comment: I recommend the `&&` solution.  Using `set -e` is tricky and it often doesn't behave as you expect, particularly where `cmd1` or `cmd2` are more complex.  It'll work fine for simple commands though.